# How to differentiate between login with google service account and email login (having same google account)?

Tags: authentication, gmail, google-signin

I have an account on Gmail. I have implemented login with google service on a project.
Now the Question is, What method is the optimal or the best practice which is followed regarding the account?

## There are two ways:

1. I make an account with normal email and password sign up.
2. Login with Google
   What if I use the same email and get registered with two different accounts on the project or there should be error saying "the account is already exists with this email"??

Answer (score 0):

So lets see if i follow you.

You have a system which has two login options.

- Create new user register with your email
- Login with your googel account.

In the event a user uses their gmail email address and trys to login with the ir google account your getting an error that the email already exists.

The issue being that both system are trying to create a new user.  This is where the issue is. Your system should be checking if the email exits if it does then link the accounts sources rather then creating a new user. SO the user would have to login sources one for normal login and password and the other as an external source being google.

How you achieve this depends upon your system.

Comment: I have checked and all the other platforms are working the same principle.
Thanks for your contribution.